# Уменьшение размера изображения в корзине

Tags: php, virtuemart, resize

Как уменьшить размер изображения товара в корзине `virtuemart_2`? По умолчанию выводится *preview*, но она большая.

```
<span class="cart-images">
    <?php
    if (!empty($prow->image))
        echo $prow->image->displayMediaThumb('', false);
    ?>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось гораздо проще: добавил в vm.css

```
.cart-images img{
 width: 100px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю, что вы хотите что-то вроде этого:

```
str_replace('img', 'img width="100"', $subject)$prow->image->displayMediaThumb('', false));
```

Просто в HTML или в CSS добавьте значение `width`.

Comment: ` <span class="cart-images">
             <?php
      if (!empty($prow->image)) {
       echo str_replace('img', 'img width="100"', $subject)$prow->image->displayMediaThumb ('', FALSE);
      }
      ?>
            </span> `

Comment: Я правильно ваш код вставил?

Comment: в HTML или в CSS добавьте значение width - а куда добавить?

Comment: Правильно по идее